# Spring.net [Required] attribute

Tags: spring.net

The Spring documentation [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#object-factory-extension-opp-examplesrapp) discusses the use of a [Required] attribute to inject objects into code. I've removed injection through the constructor from my code and setup a setter as provided in the example. However, I cannot get this to work. Is anybody using this successfully ?

Comment: First of all the feature works in 2.0M (only tested on with this version), however I suppose this will not solve your issues. You should post your config, write down what you have tried so far etc.

Comment: Have you enabled the postprocessor as it mentions just after `There is one last little piece of Spring configuration that is required to actually 'switch on' this behavior`.. ?